# How to convert associative array into the format specified?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have outputted the multidimensional array of directories where dimensions in depth are the subfolders.

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  ["tt"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["nn"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["fff"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["testgg"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["fff"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ggg"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ttttt"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["kk"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["bb"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["ssssss"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["test"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["dd"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ew"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["re"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["ffff"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["hh"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["eeeee"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["fff"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["test"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(30) "Save-Image-File-Formats-2a.png"
        ["nnn"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["bbb"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ["sss"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I need to make all the keys into a string in the format below

**Format**

```
{
    text: "Parent 1",
    nodes: [
        {
            text: "Child 1",
            nodes: [
                {
                    text: "Grandchild 1"
                },
                {
                    text: "Grandchild 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Child 2",
            test: "hell yea"
        }
    ]
},
{
    text: "Parent 2"
},
{
    text: "Parent 3"
},
{
    text: "Parent 4"
},
{
    text: "Parent 5"
}
```

Where the child nodes represent the subfolders.

How can I implement a recursive function to convert the array into a string with the above format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function tree($data) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $result[$key] = $value;
            continue;
        }
        if (count($value) === 0) {
            $result[] = ['text' => $key];
        } else {
            $result[] = ['text' => $key, 'nodes' => tree($value)];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$data = [
    'Parent 1' => [
        'Child 1' => [
            'Grandchild 1' => [],
            'Grandchild 2' => []
        ],
        'Child 2' => [],
    ],
    'Parent 2' => []
];

echo json_encode(tree($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "text": "Parent 1",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "text": "Child 1",
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "text": "Grandchild 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Grandchild 2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "Child 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Parent 2"
    }
]
```